Fix Ckeditor missing style css when build ckeditor
I am customizing ckeditor based on ckeditor5-build-classic but after npm run build and tested sample/index.html but my ckeditor form is missing css style. Please help me fix it, thank you guys

I am customizing ckeditor based on ckeditor5-build-classic but after npm run build and tested sample/index.html but my ckeditor form is missing css style. Please help me fix it, thank you guys
file webpack.config.js
'use strict';

 const path = require('path');
 const webpack = require('webpack');
 const { bundler, styles } = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev- 
 utils');
 const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev- 
 webpack-plugin');
 const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
devtool: 'source-map',
performance: { hints: false },

entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'ckeditor.js'),

output: {
    // The name under which the editor will be exported.
    library: 'AdvancedEditor',

    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'ckeditor.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default'
},

optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            terserOptions: {
                output: {
                    // Preserve CKEditor 5 license comments.
                    comments: /^!/
                }
            },
            extractComments: false
        })
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
        // UI language. Language codes follow the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1 format.
        // When changing the built-in language, remember to also change it in the editor's configuration (src/ckeditor.js).
        language: 'en',
        additionalLanguages: 'all'
    }),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
        banner: bundler.getLicenseBanner(),
        raw: true
    })
],

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['raw-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: {
                        injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                        attributes: {
                            'data-cke': true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader' // Thêm loader này để xử lý CSS trước khi postcss-loader
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [
                                require('postcss-import')(),
                                require('postcss-preset-env')({
                                    stage: 0,
                                    autoprefixer: { grid: true }
                                }),
                                require('cssnano')({
                                    preset: 'default',
                                }),
                            ],
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                            },
                        },

                        // minify: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

resolve: {
    symlinks: false
},

devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'sample')
}

};
